# How can I check toggle buttons group?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I have a question related to material toggle buttons group. How can I check is any of toggle buttons in group selected? If any of buttons in group is selected then button 'Next' will be active, else button 'Next' will be inactive. Should I check each toggle button or there is a way to check group of toggle buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `getCheckedButtonIds()` to get all selected buttons.

To check if no buttons are selected you can use:

```
if (group.checkedButtonIds.isEmpty()){
    //...
}
```

Comment: @sb69lg It returns the identifiers of the selected `MaterialButton`s in this group.When no
buttons are selected, returns an empty list.

Comment: Yes you can use .isEmpty()